# Make Soup Not Getting All Data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-beautifultable

I will apologize now as I am sure the format of my question and the information I provide will not be up to par with what is expected on this site. I have been coding SQL and VBA for several years and I am trying to pick up a 3rd language to enhance my skill set.  I will get better with time.

Now to my issue...

I am trying to scrape a series of tables with code that has worked on BasketballReference.com however on NBA.com the code brings back nothing. When digging further the make_soup does not contain the tr and td tags that I see when inspecting the table in my browser.  Below is the code I am using and for reference a picture of what my csv file looks like.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import csv
import time

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

with open('PlayTypeKey.csv', 'r') as PlaytypeData:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(PlaytypeData)

    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []

    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        a1 = row[0]
        b1 = row[1]
        c1 = row[2]
        d1 = row[3]

        a.append(a1)
        b.append(b1)
        c.append(c1)
        d.append(d1)

playerdatasaved = ""
i = 0

while i < 5:
    soup = make_soup("http://stats.nba.com/players/"+a[i]+"/?Season="+b[i]+"&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&PerMode="+c[i]+"&OD="+d[i])

    for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
        playerdata = b[i]+ a[i] + ","
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            playerdata=playerdata+","+data.text
        playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]
    i=i+1

header = "Season,PlayType,PLAYER,TEAM,GP,POSS,FREQ,PPP,PTS,FGM,FGA,FG%,EFG%,FT-Freq,TO-Freq,SF-Freq,AND ONE-Freq,SCORE-Freq,PERCENTILE"

file = open(os.path.expanduser("BasketballPlayTypeData.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore'))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore'))
```

PlayTypeKey.csv data:

```
PlayType    Season  Mode    OffDef
isolation   2015-16 Totals  offensive
isolation   2016-17 Totals  offensive
isolation   2017-18 Totals  offensive
transition  2015-16 Totals  offensive
transition  2016-17 Totals  offensive
transition  2017-18 Totals  offensive
```

My limited ability to trouble shoot tells me that the table data is not coming back when I make the soup out of the URL.  When printing the text of the soup I get this...

```
window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,t,n){function r(n){if(!t[n]){var o=t[n]={exports:{}};e[n][0].call(o.exports,function(t){var o=e[n][1][t];return r(o||t)},o,o.exports)}return t[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function o(e,t,n){return function(){return i(e,[f.now()].concat(u(arguments)),t?null:this,n),t?void 0:this}}var i=e("handle"),a=e(2),u=e(3),c=e("ee").get("tracer"),f=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],d="api-",l=d+"ixn-";a(p,function(e,t){s[t]=o(d+t,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=o(d+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=o(d+"routeName",!0),t.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,t){var n={},r=this,o="function"==typeof t;return i(l+"tracer",[f.now(),e,n],r),function(){if(c.emit((o?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[f.now(),r,o],n),o)try{return t.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],n),e}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[f.now()],n)}}}};a("setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,t){m[t]=o(l+t)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),i("err",[e,f.now()])}},{}],2:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){var n=[],r="",i=0;for(r in e)o.call(e,r)&&(n[i]=t(r,e[r]),i+=1);return n}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],3:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){t||(t=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-t||0,i=Array(o<0?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=e[t+r];return i}t.exports=r},{}],4:[function(e,t,n){t.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function o(e){function t(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?c(e,u,i):i()}function n(n,r,o,i){if(!d.aborted||i){e&&e(n,r,o);for(var a=t(o),u=m(n),c=u.length,f=0;f<c;f++)u[f].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[n]];return p&&p.push([b,n,r,a]),a}}function l(e,t){v[e]=m(e).concat(t)}function m(e){return v[e]||[]}function w(e){return p[e]=p[e]||o(n)}function g(e,t){f(e,function(e,n){t=t||"feature",y[n]=t,t in s||(s[t]=[])})}var v={},y={},b={on:l,emit:n,get:w,listeners:m,context:t,buffer:g,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function i(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(d.aborted=!0,s=d.backlog={})}var u="nr@context",c=e("gos"),f=e(2),s={},p={},d=t.exports=o();d.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){if(o.call(e,t))return e[t];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,t,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return e[t]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n,r){o.buffer([e],r),o.emit(e,t,n)}var o=e("ee").get("handle");t.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(e,t,n){function r(e){var t=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==t&&"function"!==t?-1:e===window?0:a(e,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=e("gos");t.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,t,n){function r(){if(!x++){var e=h.info=NREUM.info,t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&t))return s.abort();f(y,function(t,n){e[t]||(e[t]=n)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+h.offset],null,"api");var n=d.createElement("script");n.src="https://"+e.agent,t.parentNode.insertBefore(n,t)}}function o(){"complete"===d.readyState&&i()}function i(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+h.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return E.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(u=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),u))-h.offset}var u=(new Date).getTime(),c=e("handle"),f=e(2),s=e("ee"),p=window,d=p.document,l="addEventListener",m="attachEvent",w=p.XMLHttpRequest,g=w&&w.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:p.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:w,REQ:p.Request,EV:p.Event,PR:p.Promise,MO:p.MutationObserver};var v=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1071.min.js"},b=w&&g&&g[l]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),h=t.exports={offset:u,now:a,origin:v,features:{},xhrWrappable:b};e(1),d[l]?(d[l]("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1),p[l]("load",r,!1)):(d[m]("onreadystatechange",o),p[m]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",u],null,"api");var x=0,E=e(4)},{}]},{},["loader"]);
NBA.com/Stats  | Players Isolation 
























window.nbaStatsRoute = '/players/isolation/';












Scores
Schedule
News
Video
Standings
Stats
Players
Teams


NBA LEAGUE PASS
Store
Tickets
















Stats Home






{{ player.name }} 





Profile

Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage
Shooting
Career
Box Scores
Advanced Box Scores Traditional
Advanced Box Scores Advanced
Advanced Box Scores Misc
Advanced Box Scores Scoring
Advanced Box Scores Usage
Shots Dashboard
Rebounds Dashboard
Passes Dashboard
Defense Dashboard






{{ team.city }} {{ team.name }} 





Profile
Traditional
Advanced
Four Factors
Misc
Scoring
Opponent
Shooting

Lineups Traditional
Lineups Advanced
Lineups Four Factors
Lineups Misc
Lineups Scoring
Lineups Opponent

Players Traditional
Players Advanced
Players Misc
Players Scoring
Players Usage

On/Off Court Traditional
On/Off Court Advanced
On/Off Court Four Factors
On/Off Court Misc
On/Off Court Scoring
On/Off Court Opponent
On/Off Court Summary

Shots Dashboard
Rebounds Dashboard
Passes Dashboard

Box Scores
Advanced Box Scores Traditional
Advanced Box Scores Advanced
Advanced Box Scores Four Factors
Advanced Box Scores Misc
Advanced Box Scores Scoring
Seasons
Year Over Year
Franchise Leaders
Historic Roster






On Off Court Compare 





Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Four Factors
Opponent






{{ game.info }} 





Box Score
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage
Four Factors
Player Tracking
Play By Play
Shotchart
Game Charts
Hustle






Fantasy Compare 





Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring






Impact 





Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Four Factors


Defense





Players 




Players Home
Player Index
Traditional Stats
Regular Season Leaders
Hustle Leaders
Advanced Leaders

All Time Leaders


General 



Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage
Opponent
Defense




Clutch 



Clutch Traditional
Clutch Advanced
Clutch Misc
Clutch Scoring
Clutch Usage




Defense 



Defense Overall
Defending Shots Overall
Defending 3 Pointers
Defending 2 Pointers
Defending Less Than 6 FT
Defending Less Than 10 FT
Defending More Than 15 FT
Opponent Shooting
By Play Type




Play Type 



Transition
Isolation
Ball Handler
Roll Man
Post Up
Spot Up
Hand Off
Cut
Off Screen
Put Backs
Misc




Tracking 



Catch & Shoot
Defensive Impact
Drives
Passing
Touches
Pull Up Shooting
Rebounding
Offensive Rebounding
Defensive Rebounding
Shooting Efficiency
Speed & Distance
Elbow Touches
Post Ups
Paint Touches




Shooting 



Shots by General Range
Shots by Shotclock
Shots by Dribbles
Shots by Touch Time
Shots by Closest Defender
Shots by Closest Defender (+10 FT)
Shooting
Opponent Shooting


Hustle Stats
Bios
Box Scores


Advanced Box Scores 



Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage






Teams 



Teams Home


All Teams 



{{ t.city }} {{ t.name }}


Traditional Stats
Hustle Leaders
Advanced Leaders



General 



Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Four Factors
Scoring
Opponent
Defense




Clutch 



Clutch Traditional
Clutch Advanced
Clutch Misc
Clutch Four Factors
Clutch Scoring
Clutch Opponent




Defense 



Defense Overall
Defending Shots Overall
Defending 3 Pointers
Defending 2 Pointers
Defending Less Than 6 FT
Defending Less Than 10 FT
Defending More Than 15 FT
Overall Opponent Shooting
By Play Type




Play Type 



Transition
Isolation
Ball Handler
Roll Man
Post Up
Spot Up
Hand Off
Cut
Off Screen
Put Backs
Misc




Tracking 



Catch & Shoot
Defensive Impact
Drives
Passing
Touches
Pull Up Shooting
Rebounding
Offensive Rebounding
Defensive Rebounding
Shooting Efficiency
Speed & Distance
Elbow Touches
Post Ups
Paint Touches




Shooting 



Shots By General Range
Shots By Shotclock
Shots By Dribbles
Shots By Touch Time
Shots By Closest Defender
Shots By Closest Defender (+10 FT)
Shooting




Opponent Shooting 



Overall Opponent Shooting
Opponent Shots By General Range
Opponent Shots By Shotclock
Opponent Shots By Dribbles
Opponent Shots By Touch Time
Opponent Shots By Closest Defender
Opponent Shots By Closest Defender (+10 FT)


Hustle Stats
Box Scores


Advanced Box Scores 



Traditional
Advanced
Four Factors
Misc
Scoring







All Time Leaders




Finals




2018 Draft Combine





Hustle Leaders




Advanced Leaders





Scores




NBA Schedule




Summer League Schedule




Standings




Franchise Leaders




{{ t.city }} {{ t.name }}




Fantasy




Fantasy News
Fantasy Compare
Fantasy Mock Draft
Fantasy Cumulative Ranking




Lineups 




Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Four Factors
Scoring
Opponent




On/Off Court by Team 




{{ t.city }} {{ t.name }}




Draft & Combine 




2018 Draft Combine
Draft History
Combine Spot Up Shooting
Combine Non-Stationary Shooting
Combine Strength & Agility
Combine Anthro




Tools 




Player Box Score Search
Team Box Score Search
Player Streak Search
Team Streak Search
Player Compare
Fantasy Compare
Impact




Stats 101




Franchise History
Statistical Minimums
Glossary
Transactions
Fantasy News
Articles
Weekly Stats Archive
FAQ
What's New
Video & Tracking Status
Video Rulebook
Contact Us




Events 




2018 Finals
2018 Playoffs
2018 Summer League
NBA Africa Game 2017

All-Star Infographics



All-Star Friday Infographic
All-Star Saturday Infographic
All-Star Sunday Infographic


2018 Draft Combine











Advanced Stats

Stats Home
Players
Teams
Advanced
Scores
Schedule
All Time Leaders








Search For A Player or Team




No Results Found




{{ ::item.city }} {{ ::item.name }}
{{ ::item.fn }} {{ ::item.ln }}
{{ ::item.fn }} {{ ::item.ln }}



See More Results

















Stats Home


      /


Players


      /


Playtype


      /


Isolation










{{ alpha }}


Sortable Player Stats
Sortable Team Stats




{{ betaText }}


Official Leaders
Advanced Leaders
Hustle Leaders
General
Clutch
Playtype
Tracking
Defense Dashboard
Shot Dashboard
Box Scores
Advanced Box Scores
Shooting
Opponent Shooting
Hustle
All Time Summary
All Time Leaders
Bios
Players List




{{ gammaText }}


Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage
Opponent
Defense




{{ gammaText }}


Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage




{{ gammaText }}


Transition
Isolation
Pick & Roll Ball Handler
Pick & Roll Roll Man
Post Up
Spot Up
Handoff
Cut
Off Screen
Putbacks
Misc




{{ gammaText }}


Drives
Defensive Impact
Catch & Shoot
Passing
Touches
Pull Up Shooting
Rebounding
Offensive Rebounding
Defensive Rebounding
Shooting Efficiency
Speed & Distance
Elbow Touches
Post Ups
Paint Touches




{{ gammaText }}


Overall
3 Pointers
2 Pointers
< 6ft.
< 10ft.
> 15ft.




{{ gammaText }}


General
Shotclock
Dribbles
Touch Time
Closest Defender
Closest Defender +10




{{ gammaText }}


Traditional
Advanced
Misc
Scoring
Usage
















Advanced Filters




Custom Filters




















GP
Games Played
Poss
Possessions
Freq
Frequency
PPP
Points Per Possession
PTS
Games Played
PTS
Points
FGM
Field Goals Made
FGA
Field Goals Attempted
FG%
Field Goal Percentage
eFG%
Effective Field Goal Percentage
FT Freq
Free Throw Frequency
TO FREQ
Turnover Frequency
SF Freq
Shooting Foul Frequency
And One Freq
And One Frequency
Score Freq
Score Frequency




Minimum of 10 min/game and 10 possessions per play type to qualify.
provided by Synergy












Copyright © 2018 NBA Media Ventures, LLC. All rights reserved.
Privacy Policy | Terms of Use | Ad Choices
NBA.com is part of Turner Sports Digital, part of the Turner Sports & Entertainment Digital Network.



      window.esi_ = {
        country: "US",
        tz: "EST",
        region: "NC",
        browser: "OTHER",
        nbarid: "1",
        nbarn: "United States"
      };



if (typeof _satellite !== 'undefined') { _satellite.pageBottom(); }






    //Set a listener for GPTRenderComplete Event
    AdFuel.addEvent(document, 'GPTRenderComplete', function(event) {
        if (event.detail && !event.detail.isEmpty) {
            var detail = event.detail;
            //If ad_bnr_atf_01 is 728x90, dispatch the global marketing slot
            if (detail.pos[0] === 'bnr_atf_01' && detail.renderedSize[0] === 728 && detail.renderedSize[1] === 90) {
                AdFuel.queueRegistry('//ssl.cdn.turner.com/ads/nba2/singles/nba_global_mktg.js', {
                    dispatch: true,
                });
            }
        }
    });

    //Dispatch nba_stats registry
    AdFuel.queueRegistry('//i.cdn.turner.com/ads/nba2/nba_stats.js', {
        dispatch: true
    });




  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-86643645-4', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');








  var hostname = window.location.hostname;
  var accountIdOverride = "";
  var nbaOmChannelPrefix = "";
  nbaOmChannelPrefix="stats.nba.com";

  //Set to use the omniture dev suite for our development hostnames, else prod
  if (hostname === "dev.stats.nba.com" || hostname === "statsv3.nba.com" || hostname === "linuxpubstats.nba.com" || hostname == "linuxpubstatsdev.nba.com"){
    accountIdOverride="nbag-n-league-dev";
  }
  else {
    accountIdOverride="nbag-n-league";
  }

    _nba.analytics.setOverride("disableAutoPage",true);
  _nba.analytics.setOverride("accountIds", accountIdOverride);

    if (_nba && _nba.settings && _nba.settings.global) {
       _nba.settings.global.experience="responsive";
    }







window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"09f0cb5c68","applicationID":"76210961","transactionName":"NgcGZUJQVxYEVEJcCQ9NMUNZHkkJBE5TRxVOCxdeXFBNDApZGVwIBQccH0BZSQ==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":17,"atts":"GkAFEwpKRBg=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}
```

Towards the bottom of what is pasted above are the headers of the table but no corresponding text or code for the table itself.  I won't clutter this post with what I get when printing the HTML but I get no hits when searching for the tr or td tags.

Thanks in advance for anyone that spends time looking into this and I just want to say this site has already been immensely valuable to me.

Comment: Code that works for one website is unlikely to work on another. Could you [edit] the question to include a few lines from your `PlayTypeKey.csv` file? (in text format) Without it is difficult to recreate your problem. Also which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Martin thank you for your response.  I have replaced the image with text and I am using Python 3.6.  I should also mention that the table is broken up into several "pages" that require navigation.  I imagine this would add a level of difficulty that may require something like RoboBrowser but I really wanted to bite this off one issue at a time.

Comment: The information you need is actually returned via a request from the page using javascript. It is returned in JSON format before being converted into HTML by the page. As such the best approach would be to use that to extract your stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage does not contain any tables with `TR` and `TD`. It is displayed by the page first requesting all of the data via a separate call and then rendering this using Javascript. Normally you would need to use something like selenium to allow this to be done, but a much faster approach is to use your browser to monitor the network requests and recreate them using Python.

In this case the request results in all of the data being return in JSON format which is much easier to parse than needing BeautifulSoup. Simply load it using Python's JSON library and you will have all the player data as one big Python data structure.

When reading your CSV file, it would be easier just to use the information a row at a time rather than trying to build multiple lists and then index them in a separate loop.

The JSON request you need takes slightly different parameters (as seen by monitoring network activity in a browser) to the ones for the HTML page you were trying to get, so the CSV file would need to be updated:

```
PlayType,Season,Mode,OffDef
isolation,2015,Totals,offensive
isolation,2016,Totals,offensive
isolation,2017,Totals,offensive
transition,2015,Totals,offensive
transition,2016,Totals,offensive
transition,2017,Totals,offensive
```

The script to get the data is as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import os
import csv
import json
from operator import itemgetter

fieldnames = ["PlayerFirstName", "PlayerLastName", "TeamNameAbbreviation", "GP", "Poss"]
req_fields = itemgetter(*fieldnames)

with open("PlayTypeKey.csv", "r", newline="") as f_input, \
     open(os.path.expanduser("BasketballPlayTypeData.csv"), "w", newline="") as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    next(csv_input)

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(fieldnames)

    for play_type, season, mode, off_def in csv_input:
        url = f"http://stats-prod.nba.com/wp-json/statscms/v1/synergy/player/?category={play_type}&limit=500&names={off_def}&season={season}&seasonType=Reg"
        print(url)
        json_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        data = json.loads(json_data)

        for player in data['results']:
            row = [season, play_type] + list(req_fields(player))
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

If you were to print `json_data` you would see all the possible data that is available for each player. I have shown how to extract the first few columns. `itemgetter()` is used as a shortcut to extracting the required bits from each player entry.

This script will give you an output CSV file starting:

```
PlayerFirstName,PlayerLastName,TeamNameAbbreviation,GP,Poss
2015,isolation,Aaron,Gordon,ORL,78,30
2015,isolation,Norman,Powell,TOR,49,9
2015,isolation,Al,Jefferson,CHA,47,9
```

You could obviously modify the output to make it identical to your other site.     The big advantage to this approach is that you will get all the player data in a single call, no need to cycle through multiple pages.

Comment: Martin I cannot thank you enough for the time you spent on this response.  As a new Python programmer you have probably saved me weeks of google and youtube searching to try to figure this out on my own.